# Can't use "lua require" before call plug#end()

Tags: vimrc, neovim, lua

I'm using this minimal setup for easy repro:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua'
lua require('nvim-tree-init')
call plug#end()
```

Running `neovim` results in this error upon opening of neovim:

```
Error detected while processing C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim:
line    3:
E5108: Error executing lua ...rs\myUser\AppData\Local\nvim/lua/nvim-tree-init.lua:9: module 'nvim-tree' not found:
    no field package.preload['nvim-tree']
    no file '.\nvim-tree.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\lua\nvim-tree.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\lua\nvim-tree\init.lua'
    no file '.\nvim-tree.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\nvim-tree.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ...rs\myUser\AppData\Local\nvim/lua/nvim-tree-init.lua:9: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

This error disappears when `lua require` line is called after `call plug#end()` line.

Why does this happen?

For `nvim-tree-init.lua`, I'm using code from [here](https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua?tab=readme-ov-file#setup).

#### Why am I doing this?

I use config model in which every `source plugin` is coupled with all of that plugins settings in separate file for each plugin.
I don't want `lua require(plugin)` to be decoupled from all other plugin settings (which are all in `plug#begin()`-`plug#end()` block).

Comment: I suspect that vim-plug plays with the vim runtime path (`rtp`) that is only restored after the `plug#end()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. You can start requiring lua modules only after `plug#end()` is called where `&runtimepath` is updated w.r.t. the registered plugins.

vim-plug is not very suited for configuring Lua plugins in a modular way; in many vim plugins configs are expected to sourced *before* the plugin sources (`plugin/*.vim`) are executed, but for Lua plugins it's not the case. If you still want to make the plugin declaration and config stay closer, then your option includes:

1. Defer the execution, e.g.:

```
vim.schedule(function()
   require('nvim-tree-init').setup(...)
end)
```

2. Use the autocmd that will be fired when plugin loads:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('User', {
  pattern = 'nvim-tree',
  callback = function()
    -- ... setup
  end,
})
```

and many more. After all, you may want to use a different plugin manager.

Comment: I wanted to stick to vim-plug since I try my best for config to be valid on both vanilla and neovim